# Override redirect_to in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, overriding

I use an engine in my rails app that logins the user and redirects to a service param (it's a CAS engine). However, from the host app I want to redirect the user (after he/she has logged in) in a different location sometimes depending on the params. At the moment I can't get it work because rails permits only 1 call of redirect_to/render. The engine inherits from my rails app ApplicationController.

How can I override/redefine redirect_to to call it multiple times?

The problem might be solved in other ways but I really don't want them. I have tried some of them but none can compete with the simplicity of just letting the last defined redirect_to take action.

I'm *only* interested in solutions that involve redefining `redirect_to` so that I can invoke it multiple times.

Comment: You're trying to break Rails. Don't do that. Just fix your app so you only call `redirect_to` once. You say you won't really want "other ways", but you way is *wrong*.

Comment: The stuff you're adding to the end of the question doesn't belong there. Please don't edit it back in.

Comment: @meagar I am trying to avoid useless answers like your answer "You're trying to break Rails". So please don't take it out again :)

Comment: You don't get to add "no downvotes please" to your question. That isn't how this site works.

Comment: Aha ok then I will remove that part.

Comment: You're still trying to break Rails. Sticking your fingers in your ears and ignoring the advice of people who actually know what they're talking about isn't going to get your very far as a software developer. You're still trying to solve your problem the completely wrong way.

Comment: @meagar is completely right. Saying "i want to do it this way and no other way will be accepted" is not something you will be able to get away with for very long. It's much better to take the advice of people more familiar with the problem then you are and use it to improve your code and coding habits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it was much easier than I thought. All you need to do is to explicitly modify the response object.
Thus you could declare the following function in ApplicationController:

```
def re_redirect_to(location, status = 303)
  response.location = location
  response.status = status
end
```

That's it basically. Elegant and simple.

As I said in the first post:

> I use an engine in my rails app that logins the user and redirects to a service param (it's a CAS engine). However, from the host app I want to redirect the user (after he/she has logged in) in a different location sometimes depending on the params. At the moment I can't get it work because rails permits only 1 call of redirect_to/render. The engine inherits from my rails app ApplicationController.

So basically I had no other option than override the engine's redirect_to in an after_action in ApplicationController. I believe it's *much* better and more maintainable solution than modifying the engine's source code.

I would like to note here that it's absolutely good to follow the conventions. Definitely calling redirect_to more than once should be avoided in 99% cases. But it's good to know that there is a way to deal with that other 1%. Conventions are just conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can "override" it. You can redefine any method in any object at any point in Ruby. However, this is a *terrible* idea. You should fix your problem, which is that you're calling `redirect_to` twice, instead of hacking apart Rails in order to allow your problem to continue.

If you're still set on "fixing" this the wrong way, find the source code (this was trivially easy to do), copy it into an initializer/library file of your own, and make the modifications.

```
module ActionController::Redirecting
  def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
    raise ActionControllerError.new("Cannot redirect to nil!") unless options
    raise AbstractController::DoubleRenderError if response_body

    self.status        = _extract_redirect_to_status(options, response_status)
    self.location      = _compute_redirect_to_location(options)
    self.response_body = "<html><body>You are being <a href=\"#{ERB::Util.h(location)}\">redirected</a>.</body></html>"
  end
end
```

If you really want to do this, despite being forewarned that it is the *wrong* solution to your problem and that you're fundamentally altering behavior of Rails that other things may depend on, comment out the line that raises a `DoubleRenderError`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is it terrible idea? Btw one of my solutions was to explicetly set response.location and response.status for overriding redirect_to which I think is more elegant.

Comment: @Filippos It's a terrible idea because it's going to have unintended consequences in other parts of your code more than likely. Modifying the redirect_to code is like taking an axe to the problem when an exacto knife is needed. Fix your code so that it no longer attempts to double render by, say, wrapping the redirects in if/else statements or case statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unless I edit engine's code I can't see any other way doing it.

Comment: @Filippos if you posted a code example we might be able to offer a better way.

Comment: It would be *much* better for you to modify the engine's code than Rails' code

Comment: I disagree. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, in the application controller, override redirect, do your thing, then call super:

```
class ApplicationControler < ... #depends on your rails version
    def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
        # do your custom thing here
        super # and call the default rails redirect
```

Hope this helps,
Kevin